# Does file content fully exist in library files

Tags: python, linux, perl, bash

I have just completed the refactoring of a long piece of code.

My refactoring included breaking up the source code into many functions in many files at many folders.

Now that I'm done, I want to make sure that there aren't lines in the original code that are not present in one of the new files I have created.

A pseudo code for my need is something like this :

```
for line in sourceCode:
    if length(grep line refacoredLib)==0:
        print line + " does not exist in refactored code"
```

My first thought is to write a python\bash implementation, is there a more elegant solution you know of?
Thanks!

Comment: "one-liner"? Probably not. "elegant one-liner" definitely not. And why  do you want it to be only one line? That's a pretty pointless requirement.

Comment: Thanks, indeed no need for it to be in one line.

Comment: Not a proper answer, but refactoring without automated regression tests is not necessarily a great idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could compare sets of lines in Python, but that wouldn't be a one-liner.

```
source_files = ['source1.py', 'source2.py']
new_files = ['new1.py', 'new2.py']

old_lines, new_lines = set(), set()
for source in source_files:
   with open(source) as sf:
       old_lines.update(sf)
for new in new_files:
   with open(new) as nf:
       new_lines.update(nf)
for line in old_lines - new_lines:
    print line + " does not exist in refactored code"
```

Comment: Wouldn't `old_lines - new_lines` be more useful?

Answer (score 6):

Or, if you don't want to reinvent the wheel:

```bsh
cat newfiles/* | sort > /tmp/new
cat oldfile.py | sort > /tmp/old
comm -23 /tmp/old /tmp/new
```

Not Python, I know, but still.